# Render from multiple cameras switching automatically

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, camera

I've pre-set a bunch of cameras in my scene for a short animation.
When I setup the different cameras.  I set markers, with  <kbd>M</kbd> in my timeline, then after using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>0</kbd>, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>B</kbd> I was able to set to my active camera switch as I desired.

I have like 9 cameras, and when I press  <kbd>Space</kbd> in my viewport, the sequence uses the camera's properly. It changes exactly how it should. But when it comes render time, there are no camera changes and it's stuck in one camera angle for the whole animation.

Why are my cameras not switching and rendering out as they should be?

For reference I used the tutorial 'Cutting Between Multiple Cameras - Blender Tutorial' (from 24 Jan 2019) that can be found on youtube. I'm also running blender 3.0.

I guess I can just render each camera angle out separately but I'd love to know how to use this function properly.

Comment: You should be able to 1) select a camera in the outliner. 2) go to a frame in the timeline. 3) type M CTRL+B to cause the animation to switch to that camera on that frame.  The timeline should then show the dotted line for a marker, a camera icon, and the name of the camera.  This should carry through to the animation.  Can you paste an image of your timeline, or better yet add a simple blend file that shows the problem to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Thanks for your reply! A few hours after playing with the settings. I saved rebooted blender and now it seems to work. I triple checked all the marks and dotted lines and it's now rendering as it should be.

I did end up redoing all the marks, M with control+0 and then control+b. Thanks for the help.